# Show that $(P\land Q) ↔ P \equiv P\rightarrow Q$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Can someone help me to complete verify $(P\land Q) ↔ P \equiv P\rightarrow Q$ using laws of equivalence

```
(A Λ B) ↔ A                     Left hand side of the equivalence
((AΛB)→A) Λ (A→(AΛB))           Bi-implication in terms of implication 
((AΛB)’ V A) Λ (A’V (AΛB))      Implication in terms of v
```

This is my progress. I don't know what law to use next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\fa}[2]{\forall #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\ex}[2]{\exists #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\exun}[2]{\exists ! #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
%$

$$\calc
     (P\land Q)\equiv P
\op\equiv\hint{opening the biconditional statement}
    \Bigr[(P\land Q)\rightarrow P\Bigr]\land\Bigr[P\rightarrow(P\land Q)\Bigr]
\op\equiv\hint{conditional law}
    \Bigr[\lnot(P\land Q)\lor P\Bigr]\land\Bigr[\lnot P\lor(P\land Q)\Bigr]
\op\equiv\hint{DeMorgan's law on the left and distributivity on the right}
    \Bigr[(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)\lor P\Bigr]\land\Bigr[(\lnot P\lor P)\land(\lnot P\lor Q)\Bigr]
\op\equiv\hint{commutativity on the left and tautology on the right}
\Bigr[P\lor(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)\Bigr]\land\Bigr[\text{tautology}\ \land (\lnot P\lor Q)\Bigr]
\op\equiv\hint{associativity on the left and tautology law on the right}
\Bigr[(P\lor\lnot P)\lor\lnot Q\Bigr]\land(\lnot P\lor Q)
\op\equiv\hint{tautology law on the left}
\text{tautology}\ \land(\lnot P\lor Q)
\op\equiv\hint{tautology law}
\lnot P\lor Q
\op\equiv\hint{conditional law}
P\rightarrow Q
\endcalc$$

Is every step clear$?$